# Mechanical keyboard needs long time to initialize after Windows 7 Boot

Tags: windows-7, keyboard

I have a Q-Pad MK-85 mechanical keyboard. When booting up windows, it needs a very long time (about 20 seconds) to get activated. Shortly after boot the lights on the keyboard light up but keys pressed are not recognized. For this time I cannot enter my password or use the mouse that is connected to the keyboard's USB hub.

**Just to clarify: The issue is the same with no mouse connected to the USB hub. Drivers and Windows updates are up-to-date.**

The keyboard works fine in UEFI/BIOS and as well Windows after that initialization phase. It just bugs me that I need to wait that long to log into windows.

The issue first occurred after updating the BIOS of my ASUS Sabertooth X79 mainboard. I had to update it to be able to use a newer graphics card. May be a conincidence but that was the first time I noticed this behaviour.

Anyone had similar problems with that keyboard or another mechanical keyboard and knows how to fix it?

System specs at a glance:

- Windows 7 Professional x64
- ASUS Sabertooth X79 mainboard
- Q-Pad MK-85 mechanical keyboard

[UPDATE] BIOS settings for USB

- Legacy USB Support: enabled
- Lagacy USB 3.0 Support: enabled
- EHCI Hand-off: disabled

Comment: What are the USB settings in BIOS for: Legacy USB Support, Legacy USB 3.0 Support and EHCI Hand-off?

Comment: I updated the question to reflect these settings

Comment: Have you tried plugging the keyboard into a USB 2 socket (i.e. *not* a blue one)?

Comment: It was in USB 2 before, tried USB 3 now. Behaves the same in both ports.

Comment: @marandus Do you have a different computer you can test the keyboard on/different keyboard you can test on the same computer? Have you tried disabling the legacy USB support? If that doesn't help, you can contact QPAD technical support. (To make sure I'm notified of your reply here, you can use "@AndrewMorton" in your reply, like I used at the start of this comment.)

Comment: @AndrewMorton I have a notebook I can test it on. Will report back when I did that.

Comment: @AndrewMorton disabling legacy USB support did not change anything. The test with the notebook was successful, but that could be caused by the long overall boot time of that thing. It is quite old. Maybe I'll contact QPAD now or just live with it. Thanks for your help anyway.